# Stanford NLP Tree LSTM running error

Tags: macos, lua, stanford-nlp, lstm

I'm testing the codes offered by Stanford NLP, and followed the instruction in https://github.com/stanfordnlp/treelstm

However, when I test this `th sentiment/main.lua -m constituency -b`

I got this error:

```
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Constituency Tree LSTM for Sentiment Classification 
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /Users/Solomon/torch/install/bin/luajit: 
    /Users/Solomon/Downloads/treelstm-master/util/Vocab.lua:19: 
    attempt to index local 'file' (a nil value)
    >stack traceback:
    /Users/Solomon/Downloads/treelstm-master/util/Vocab.lua:19: in function '__init'
    /Users/Solomon/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torch/init.lua:91: in function </Users/Solomon/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torch/init.lua:87>
    [C]: in function 'Vocab'
    sentiment/main.lua:48: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'dofile'
    ...omon/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:145: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x0104141d50
```

it was run under OSX Yosemite, spent hours and hours but couldn't figure it out. I am new to these things, someone knows what's wrong?

Comment: Read the error `attempt to index local file (a nil value)` and the origin `Vocab.lua`. I would bet that you have forgot to set some configuration which specifies the path of the vocabulary file.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. cp glove.840B.300d.zip data/glove folder 
2. unzip glove.840B.300d.zip inside data/glove folder 
3. run the following     command
4. th scripts/convert-wordvecs.lua data/glove/glove.840B.300d.txt data/glove/glove.840B.vocab data/glove/glove.840B.300d.th
```

**You will see something like**

```
Converting data/glove/glove.840B.300d.txt to Torch serialized format
count = 2196017
dim = 300
```

**Then run the following command **

```
th sentiment/main.lua --model constituency --layers 4 --dim 300 --epochs 2

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Constituency Tree LSTM for Sentiment Classification
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
loading word embeddings
unk count = 976
loading datasets
num train = 8544

num dev   = 1101
num test  = 2210
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
model configuration
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
max epochs = 2
fine grained sentiment    = true
num params                = 1085105
num compositional params  = 1083600
word vector dim           = 300
Tree-LSTM memory dim      = 300
regularization strength   = 1.00e-04
minibatch size            = 25
learning rate             = 5.00e-02
word vector learning rate = 1.00e-01
dropout                   = true
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Training model
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- epoch 1
```